# Regex pattern [TableName].[FieldName]

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string for a calculation field which contain fields, operators, functions, etc.
I need to extract fields from this string. Fields are in format: [TableName].[FieldName], where TableName and FieldName mai contain spaces.
I solved the problem for TableName and FieldName without spaces with regex:

```
    List<string> fieldsFound = new List<string>();
    string pattern = @"\[(\w*)(\])(\.)(\[)(\w*)(\])";
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(formula, pattern))
    {
        fieldsFound.Add(match.Value);
    }
```

So, I need a pattern which can allow spaces inside TableName and FieldName.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `\w` and `\s` into a character class inorder to match both word and space characters.

```
\[([\w\s]*)(\])(\.)(\[)([\w\s]*)(\])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vJ1cP1/5)

**OR**

Use the below regex if you don't want to capture leading, trailing spaces inside the `[]`,

```
\[\s*([\w\s]*?)\s*\]\.\[\s*([\w\s]*?)\s*\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vJ1cP1/6)

Comment: Excelent! I don't need to trailing spaces inside []. First solution is what I need.